# Adding an Arduino variant into ~/sketchbook and using it from a Makefile

Tags: arduino-ide, build

I have a `pins_arduino.h` file for a given Arduino variant, installed in `~/sketchbook/hardware/attiny/variants/tiny14/pins_arduino.h`. The IDE has no problem picking it up if I set the right board type. However, if I use a `Makefile` like this:

```
BOARDS_TXT      = $(HOME)/sketchbook/hardware/attiny/boards-cli.txt
BOARD_TAG       = attiny44-8

include /usr/share/arduino/Arduino.mk
```

then running `make` fails to compile it because of a missing `pins_arduino.h`. Moving the `tiny14` directory to `/usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/variants`  fixes the problem, but I don't want to pollute my system directory (and also, it sounds fragile if I ever remove/replace my Arduino software distribution).

How do I get the CLI `Make` toolchain to pick up my `pins_arduino.h` file from my `~/sketchbook`?